# The requesterd URl could not be found AJAX

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.net application, when i run it the page load but the method which are AJAX method they do not load. and i get this error.

Error 1:

> /ajax/UserControls_WebUserControl,App_Web_webusercontrol.ascx.6bb32623.ssiyzisi.ashx

I have re-install AJAX, check the reference of the AJAXControlToolKit.dll path in bin and so on...
In `web.config` file I am using:

```
<add verb="POST,GET" path="ajax/*.ashx" type="Ajax.PageHandlerFactory, Ajax" />
```

But with no luck.

Error 2:

> Description: HTTP 404. The resource
>   you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed,
>   had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please
>   review the following URL and make sure
>   that it is spelled correctly.

Comment: I'm confused, could someone tell me what it means to be using AJAX 3.5?  I thought AJAX was AJAX.

Comment: @Tom Gullen I got confused typing that, however i took that out :)

Comment: @Antisanity I took that out now. Can you suggest me what may be the problem with it?

Comment: @antisanity yes and i get this error missing this file .ashx

Comment: @Safi - I fear there's some confusion about what you're using, etc. The `Ajax.PageHandlerFactory` HttpHandler you mention in the web.config uses the AjaxPro/AjaxPro2 library from http://www.ajaxpro.info/, and should normally be referenced as `type="AjaxPro.AjaxHandlerFactory, AjaxPro"`. This isn't usually required for the AJAXControlToolkit however, but obviously you could be using the two side-by-side quite happily.

Comment: @Zhaph-Ben Duguid Well i have tried on your solution as well, but it is not working, although i just created another small project and did the same it worked but in this case it is not working?:(

Comment: Please post some relevant code.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, i am using a script Manager, then in the methods i am Making the methods as Ajax methods like [Ajax.......], in the bin folder i have the ajaxcontroltoolkit.dll, in the webconfig file i have  `add verb="POST,GET" path="ajax/*.ashx" type="Ajax.PageHandlerFactory, Ajax" /> ` i have code for just the methods, `[Ajax.AjaxMethod(Ajax.HttpSessionStateRequirement.ReadWrite)]` the page on which i have put the ajax method, does not run and display this Error 1. which is in the above post.

Comment: @safi the first "error" is not an error it's just path of some file.. please post the real and full error message plus stack trace and maybe it will shed some light.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, i get the following error on script manager, Error in creating the control?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard yes, when i create script manager on Webusercontrol it works but on the default.aspx i get this error

Comment: You must have the ScriptManager in the top level page right after the `<form runat="server">` part - maybe that's your problem.. ?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard when i run my application, the system gives this error, .ashx file not found what may be the problem causing this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use [Page Methods](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Using_Page_Methods_in_ASPNET_AJAX.aspx)?  If so, you need to enable usage of them in the ScriptManager control that is on the page or master page.

Comment: i have figured out the problem, it was problem of IIS server, which was running,so i changed in the app pool to run my application in classic pool.